# How to solve the system with the proper solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Find all the values of the parameter p for which the following system: $$\begin{cases}px + 3y = -p \\ 3x+py  \; \;= 8 \end{cases}$$ has $x \ge 0, y\ge 0$ solutions.

I got $(-3;8]$ but in answers there is $[-3;0]$. Just added the two equations and got $$x+y=(8-p)/(p+3).$$ Where is the mistake? Please help me without using calculus. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: From the first equation we get
$$y=-\frac{1}{3}(p+px)$$ plugging this in the second equation we obtain
$$3x-\frac{p^2}{3}-\frac{p^2}{3}x=8$$ so $$x(9-p^2)=24+p^2$$
Can you finish?
From the solution for $$x$$ we know that $$9>p^2$$ or $$3>|p|$$  for $y$ we get
$$y=-\frac{11p}{9-p^2}$$ Since we have $$3>|p|$$ we get $$-11p<0$$ so $$p<0$$ and we get for $p$: $$-3<p<0$$

Comment: Thanks, but I got [-3;3], but answer is [-3;0].

Comment: If $$p\ne \pm 3$$ then we get $$x=\frac{24+p^2}{9-p^2}$$

Comment: Do you want to know $y$?

Comment: all the values of the parameter p for which the system has x≥0,y≥0 solutions.